# Inferring a single port RAM in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, intel-fpga

I am trying to make a 32x4 (32 words, 4-bit) single port RAM block. Here is my Verilog code:

```
module RAM_array (input clk, wren, input [4:0] address,
                        input [3:0] data, output reg [3:0] q);

    reg [3:0] mem [31:0]; // a 4 bit wide 32 word RAM block.

    always @(posedge clk) begin
            if (wren)
                mem[address] <= data;
            q <= mem[address];
    end
endmodule
```

Since I'm using Altera's Cyclone V chip on a DE-1-SoC, I based my code on their guide here: http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.1/mergedProjects/hdl/vlog/vlog_pro_ram_inferred.htm

**Question: Whenever I write a value to an address in the block I have to wait an extra clock cycle for it to get written. Why so?**

Comment: Do you mean "wait an extra clock cycle for it to get written" or do you mean "wait an extra clock cycle for the `q` output to change"? Given how you have written your code, it takes 2 clock cycles for output `q` to change.

Comment: Can you elaborate on in what sense an extra cycle of latency is inserted here? Try a blocking assignment if you want `q` to reflect the new value on the next cycle. At least Verilog is hardly my forte but I would be surprised if the synthesizer decided to map the logic to a block with different semantics than the code itself.

Comment: since you use 'non-blocking' assignment in the code, q will always get the old value of mem[address]. so, if data changed, say to '1' and mem[address] was '0' before, verilog will assign '1' to 'mem' but after it assignes '0' to q. So, you need next clock cycle to propagate the value to 'q'.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. If I wanted the value of q to change the very next clock cycle, would using a blocking assignment be the only way to achieve this? Isn't using blocking assignments in sequential always block poor style? Or would this be an exception to the guideline (I'm pretty sure there must be a way to improve my design rather than use blocking statements...)

Comment: Yes, using blocking on the **outputs** of the flop block is **bad**.  You can use it on the internal temps though. But you are asking a different question now. And therefore a question for you: how it is supposed to work in your design?

Comment: In my design q is fed as an input to a 7 segment hex display on my fpga board. Based on my input switches where I will specify the write enable, data and address, I can either read values or write values to the RAM block. Just a little experiment where I wanted to build an inferred RAM block rather than use the IP Cores in Quartus.

Comment: Based on the FPGA device, Quartus can infer "Old data" on Read vs "New Data" on Read and create corresponding pass-through logic for "New Data" on Read. The code above illustrates old data on read which is better from timing closure standpoint. You can read more about modelling RAMS in Section 4.4.1.5, and 4.4.1.6 in [Quartus Prime Reference Manual](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/qts/qts-qpp-handbook.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments & answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you see the "extra clock cycle" when you try to read one clock cycle after you write, but still get the old value.
This happens since you are using a non-blocking assignments when you write to mem, **and when you drive the output q**. 
Therefore, it takes you one clock cycle to write to mem and one clock cycle to read from it. In total it's two cycles.

If you want to reduce the memory latency, use concurrent statement and "assign" the output q. 
This will implement a simple wire from mem to the output q:

```
module RAM_array (input clk, wren, input [4:0] address,
                    input [3:0] data, output [3:0] q);

    reg [3:0] mem [31:0]; // a 4 bit wide 32 word RAM block.

    always @(posedge clk) 
            if (wren)
                mem[address] <= data;

    assign q = mem[address];

endmodule
```

The synthesizer should choose to implement this code with FFs, and not SRAM block (this is exactly the behavior of a FF --> zero cycles read latency, 1 cycle write latency). 
This is OK and shouldn't affect your synthesis since it's a very small array.

Comment: Thanks! So the implication of this is if I have an SRAM block with significantly larger dimensions, if I need to reduce the latency I would need to have some kind of "new data" vs "old data" on read-during-write behaviour as suggested by Pulimon? Since it wouldn't really be a good idea to use, say, 32k flip flops instead of an sram block...

Comment: Not all FPGA devices support this kind of memory with a SRAM block. 
Also, note that this kind of SRAM can have zero write latency - there is a bypass from write to read when it's the same address.
In general, for large memory as 32Kb I wouldn't recommend it, unless timing is not an issue for you.
IMO the correct practice for the scenario you are describing is to use your original SRAM with the latency, and modify the RTL that interacts with it to expect the latency. But again, it's all a matter of needs and resources